# DLL missing when COM+ application client proxy is exported on Windows 2003 Server and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003, com+

On Windows 2003 Server and Windows 7 when a COM+ application client proxy is exported, the DLL which is proxied is not included in the MSI file that is created.  The MSI will install, but since the DLL is not included, the remote application cannot be instantiated.

The same COM+ application exported from a Windows 2000 server includes the DLL, however the installer won't run on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 1):

**WHY IS DLL MISSING FROM COM+ APPLICATION EXPORTED ON WINDOWS 2003 SERVER OR GREATER?**
You can no longer install COM+ DLLs into the System32 folder on the server.  In Windows 2003 server and beyond (including Windows 7) when exporting COM+ package any DLLs registered in Windows\System32 (or folders below that) will not be exported.  According to Microsoft Support, this is by design.  *(This information has not been published publicly by Microsoft, so we had to open a ticket with them to discover the issue.)*

The symptoms are that the exported MSI files do not contain the COM+ DLLs if:
  1. the COM+ DLL is registered in System32 and
  2. the COM+ package is exported on Windows 2003 or later.
The MSI will be created and will install, however the applications will not be able to instantiate the objects because the DLL was never installed.  Opening the MSI with a install editor like Wise Installation Editor will reveal that the DLL is not included in the MSI.

The answer is to register your COM+ application DLLs in a folder other than Windows\System32.

**WHY WON'T A COM+ APPLICATION EXPORTED FROM WINDOWS 2000 SERVER INSTALL ON WINDOWS 7?**
There are two versions of COM+:  v1.0 and v1.5.  Different operating systems export and install various combinations of these versions:

**Exporting Client Proxies**
  -Server 2000 exports the 1.0 format
  -Windows 2003 can export either 1.0 or 1.5
  -Windows 2008/7 can only export 1.5
**Installing Client Proxies**
  -Windows XP can install proxies in either 1.0 or 1.5 format
  -Windows 7 can only install proxies in 1.5 format

COM+ applications must be exported on Windows 2003 or greater in the COM+ 1.5 format to install on both Windows XP and Windows 7 clients.